# Let me ask this again because people told me system( system of equations) is independent if there is no solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the system (system of equations) has no solution, I know it is inconsistent. However, is the SYSTEM also independent? I am not saying linearly independent.

I have been googling this. At least $99\%$ of the answer from google says if the system is inconsistent, the system is not even independent or dependent, but the answer I got from below links is independent.

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75KFE.png)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBDpC.png)

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/systems-of-linear-equations/possible-number-of-solutions-of-systems-of-linear-equations/v/independent-and-dependent-systems

Comment: The above link says "independent system has a single solution." So why are you saying "I know it is inconsistent" (your first sentence).

Comment: my bad, i corrected the mistake.

Comment: If you have already found "at least 99%" agreement about the answer, why are you asking here?

Comment: `If the system (system of equations) has no solution, I know it is consistent` You mean inconsistent right ?

Comment: yes, my bad. I meant inconsistent.

Comment: Dietrich Burde, that is why I don't understand. My professor told me if the system is inconsistent, the system and the answer is "system independent" similar to linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

A system of equations is either consistent or inconsistent. Consistent means that it has at least one solution. Inconsistent means it has no solutions.

Furthermore, if a system is consistent it may be dependent or independent. Dependent means that there are infinitely many solutions. Independent means that there is exactly one solution.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ It seems that the desired answer is referring to linear dependence and independence. Generally, in basic algebra textbooks, the definitions are given as above in my original answer, and the adjectives "dependent" and "independent" are reserved only for describing consistent systems, which is why I described it this way originally.

In more general terms, to say that a system is linearly independent means that there is no way to scale the equations in the system and add them together such that the result is zero (unless you scale every equation by zero). For a system of two equations this is equivalent to saying that one is not a multiple of the other.

So a system of two equations is linearly dependent if one is a multiple of the other, and it is linearly independent if one is not a multiple of the other. It is still true that only a consistent system can be linearly dependent. However, linear independence can be used to describe a consistent system, or an inconsistent system, depending on the situation.

Comment: my professor told me if it is an inconsistent system, it is independent, and I have asked this here before. People here told me if it is an inconsistent system, it is independent.

Comment: @777JonathanSum It seems your teacher is taking a more general definition of dependence and independence than is usually used in basic algebra textbooks. Specifically, he/she is referring to linear dependence and linear independence. See my edit.